Wp_options Table Huge After DDOS
IONOS VPS running Plesk and two Wordpress instances, behind Cloudflare CDN.
We seem to be suffering DDOS attacks on our website. When they happen, disk space runs out and we can no longer log into Plesk admin or Wordpress admin panels.
This morning I opened my inbox to see emails from our web hosting company with alerts that cpu usage went to 93 - 95% usage.
Accessed remote console and found disk usage was 100%.  Between the wp_options table, ibdata1 and error logs, 110GB had been used up.
Moving the error logs to a local disk allowed me to log into Plesk.  I then optimised the wp_option table using phpmyadmin and the table had shrunk to 20mb.
What can I do to prevent this happening again?

You need to examine the traffic and figure out why Cloudflare isn't blocking it from getting to your website. Make sure the bad traffic is actually going through Cloudflare, and perhaps create some new page rules or firewall rules in Cloudflare to block the traffic if you can. You might also look into increasing the security level on your Cloudflare domain.
